# How to save Active Directory list of all users in all e-mail distributions to .CSV?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0

I found this example but I am not sure how I can properly save the output to a .csv.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {GroupCategory -eq "Distribution"} -Properties Members

ForEach ($g in $Groups) {
    Write-Host $g.name
    Write-Host $g.members `n
}
```

I have tried something such as:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {GroupCategory -eq "Distribution"} -Properties Members

ForEach ($g in $Groups) {
    $g.name | Export-CSV C:\log.csv -notypeinformation -Append
    $g.members | Export-CSV C:\log.csv -notypeinformation -Append
}
```

It only saves 1 column to the CSV which is called length.

This also makes me remove the 'n at the end of Write-Host $g.members `n

Is there a way that I can grab this data and save it to .csv properly?

**UPDATE**

With help from TheMadTechnician and this link https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/07/22/export-user-names-and-proxy-addresses-to-csv-file/ I was able to get closer to what I want.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {GroupCategory -eq "Distribution"} -Properties Members

ForEach ($g in $Groups) {
    $g.name | Export-CSV C:\log.csv -notypeinformation -Append
    $g.members | Export-CSV C:\log.csv -notypeinformation -Append
}
$Groups | Select Name,@{L='Members_1'; E={$_.members[0]}}, @{L='Members_2';E={$_.Members[1]}}, @{L='Members_3';E={$_.Members[2]}}, @{L='Members_4';E={$_.Members[3gq]}} | Export-Csv C:\log.csv -notype
```

This gives me an output of the below in my CSV:

```
Name        Members_1                                     Members_2             ETC...                                                         

NameOfGroup CN=Stormy Daniels,OU=IT,DC=DomainName,DC=com  CN=Joe Bob,OU=IT,DC=DomainName,DC=com
```

Now the list of users can be huge so I would have to continue creating Members_3, Members_4, etc...

I'm not sure if there is a way I can specify all users or loop

```
@{L='Members_1'; E={$_.members[0]}}
```

and increment the number until all users are displayed.

I also only need the CN with the name.  I don't need the Ou= or Dc=.

Comment: `Export-Csv` is intended to convert an array of object to a CSV. What you are exporting is an array of strings. What should your intended output look like? Are you trying to just do `$Groups|Select Name,Members|Export-Csv C:\log.csv -notype`?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Find a dupe or post that as an answer!

Comment: I updated my post.  This got me much closer.  I'll keep trying some things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah this proved harder than I expected - due to the member counting (you have to do a count which can be comparable to integer).  I have added a possibility to limit result size as for large queries the active directory produces timeouts.

```
$limit_result_size = 10

$group_name = Get-ADGroup -Filter {GroupCategory -eq "Distribution"} -Properties Name, Members -ResultSetSize:$limit_result_size | Select-object name

ForEach ($name in $group_name.name) {
    If ((![String]::IsNullOrEmpty("$name")) -And ("$name" -notlike 'index')) {
        $count_members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "$name" | Measure-Object | Select-Object Count
        Write-Output "The AD group $name has $($count_members.Count) members.`n"
        For($counter = 0; $counter -lt $count_members.Count; $counter++) {
            $person = Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -eq $name} -Properties Name, Members | Select-Object Name, @{N='Members';E={$_.Members[$counter]}}
            $person.Members = $person.Members | Select-String 'CN=[0-9a-zA-Z]+' -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
            $person | export-csv -NoTypeInformation -Append -Path '<your_path>\log.csv'
        }
    }
}
```

Short description:

`(![String]::IsNullOrEmpty("$name")) -And ("$name" -notlike 'index'))` conditions which the AD group should satisfy.

`Select-String 'CN=[0-9a-zA-Z]+' -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }` Selects only `CN=string_with_numbers`. You could replace it with `CN=\w+` if you prefer.

The script produces a pair in CV `AD group` and the `CN=user_name`.  If anything else is unclear please ask.

**EDIT**

If you have spaces in the names of the *Common Names* (CN) you have to adjust the regexp to `CN=[0-9a-zA-Z\s]+`.

**EDIT 2** Adding user's email addresses.

Since your question has in the title request for emails I'll answer here without new question.  Note that this solution uses lookbehind in regexp to exclude the `CN=` from the output so it can be used as source for the user query.  It also uses a `PSCustomObject` which gathers all the information together.  I have renamed some variables to make better sense in the context of user details.

```
$limit_result_size = 10

$group_name = Get-ADGroup -Filter {GroupCategory -eq "Distribution"} -Properties Name, Members -ResultSetSize:$limit_result_size | Select-object name

ForEach ($name in $group_name.name) {
    If ((![String]::IsNullOrEmpty("$name")) -And ("$name" -notlike 'index')) {
        $count_members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "$name" | Measure-Object | Select-Object Count
        Write-Output "The AD group $name has $($count_members.Count) members.`n"
        For($counter = 0; $counter -lt $count_members.Count; $counter++) {
            $person = Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -eq $name} -Properties Name, Members | Select-Object Name, @{N='Members';E={$_.Members[$counter]}}
            $person.Members = $person.Members | Select-String '(?<=CN=)[0-9a-zA-Z\s]+' -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
            $person_details = Get-AdUser -filter {name -eq $member} -Properties mail | Select-Object mail
            $person_additional_details = [PSCustomObject]@{ group_name = $group.Name
                                                            user_name  = $group.Members
                                                            email      = $person_details.mail
                                                      }
            If ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($($person_additional_details.email))) {
                $person_additional_details.psobject.properties["email"].value = '<empty>'
            }

        # For user to see the written data
        Write-Output "AD Group: $($person_additional_details.group_name) `
AD User: $($person_additional_details.user_name) `
Users`'s email: $($person_additional_details.email)`n"

        # writing into the CSV file
        $person_additional_details | export-csv -NoTypeInformation -Append -Path '<your_path>\log.csv'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Woa, thank you!  Some of the CN names have spaces in them.  How would I include names with spaces?  I am reading on formats such as 'CN=[0-9a-zA-Z]+' but can't figure it out.

Comment: @KadeWilliams you have to add spaces to the regexp: \s, see my edit.  Anyways, I think your AD is build improperly.  What do you do if you have two people with same name and are in same group?

Comment: @KadeWilliams please don't forget to vote or/and accept the answer -https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Oh, it is incorrect. lol  I'm not the one that created it or maintains it though. :/   I was researching the first name/last name thing yesterday and read that there is supposed to be a period instead of a space between the names?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @KadeWilliams you are welcome!  The best way is to have a unique identifier like unique login name.  We have something like 20-30 thousand groups in our AD and it works flawlessly.  If you would like to add a space and a dot - `CN=[0-9a-zA-Z\s\.]+`

Comment: We don't have that many but we have quite a bit.  Unfortunately, I don't think anyone will listen to me or want to do anything about the naming convention.

Comment: Is there any easy way to attach e-mail address to the users?

Comment: @KadeWilliams not that easy you have to do additonal get-aduser query.  I can check it tomorrow if you create another question and you can add link to this one.

Comment: Don't worry about it.  It's not that big of a deal.

Comment: @KadeWilliams I have added the user details in the solution since your question contained a request for the emails in the title.  It is using custom object in powershell so make sure whoever is modifying the script knows what he is doing.

Comment: Awesome.  Do you want me to post a the question in a new post so you can answer it there and get credit?